# How to connect spyder to a postgres database?

Tags: python, postgresql, connection, spyder, data-warehouse

I am using Python with spyder and would like to directly connect to the our postgres datawarehouse to directly query data from there for further analysis.

This is what I found under the following link:
[https://www.psycopg.org/docs/]

`import psycopg`

Connect to your postgres DB
`conn = psycopg.connect("dbname=*** user=***")`

Open a cursor to perform database operations
`cur = conn.cursor()`

Execute a query
`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM my_data")`

Retrieve query results
`records = cur.fetchall()`

However, I get the following error message:

*runfile('C:/Users/.../.spyder-py3/untitled2.py', wdir='C:/Users/.../.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users....spyder-py3\untitled2.py", line 9, in 
import psycopg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg'*

Answer (score 0):

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/ -> this is what you are looking for.
Next step might be using pandas read_sql() to load the sql table into to your variable exploirer if it is not too big.

Does this help?

Comment: I checked the link and adjusted my request accordingly. The module error is confusing to me, any advice?

Comment: You need to type:
`import psycopg2`

and also download this package first if you haven't done so far.

Comment: you were successful?

Comment: Not yet, I was pasting the command in the editor, which I found out to be wrong, but writing the spyder console also doesn't seem to work. Any advice on where to write these statements in spyder?

Comment: have you installed the package? And please show your code to me. Otherwise it is too difficult to follow :)

Comment: `import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(user="...",
                                  password="...",
                                  host="...",
                                  port="...",
                                  database="...")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data.table25 limit 5")`

Answer (score 0):

Posting this in the Spyder Editor actually worked to establish a connection with the PostgreSQL Database:

```
import psycopg2  
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="...",                                   
password="...",                                   
host="...",                                   
port="...",                                   
database="...") 
cursor = connection.cursor() cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data.table25 limit 5")
```

After running the above command you can check for your rows with:

```
rows=cur.fetchall()
```